# Xcode 4.5 Update Container View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, container-view

With the new 'Container View' for iOS in Storyboards of Xcode 4.5, how do I reload/update one?

In my app, I have a container view which holds a UITableViewController. From my main view controller (the one with the container view) I need to updates the table view in the container.

Comment: iOS 6 /Xcode 4.5 stuff is under NDA. You should post this kind of question on the Apple's ADC forums.